# Is there a word for learning from the experience of others?

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to phrase something for which I am missing a word and I don't know whether it exists. Consider the following three perspectives.

- Learning from books
- Learning from *the experience of others*
- Learning from experience

Is there a word for "the experience of others" in this context?

Comment: Just 'learning from experience' implies it is your own primary sensory experience so is entirely _not_ what you are looking for. "Experience is the teacher of fools" (Livy)

Comment: There's the phrase "A wise man learns from his mistakes", which gave rise to the pithier version "A fool can learn from his mistakes, a wise man learns from other people's mistakes". Calling it "wise man learning" would confuse everyone though, so this isn't much use to you...

Comment: @AndyT Wise man learning like dead man walking. It's amazing how these things catch on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**vicarious** learning [TFD](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Vicarious+learning)

> learning through indirect experience.

Learning from the experience of others v. learning from experience:

[What is the difference between vicarious learning and observational learning?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-vicarious-learning-and-observational-learning)